# Rudin' PMA: theorem 2.36 confusion about the proof

Tags: analysis, compactness

This theorem is fully presented in this question:[Confusion in Theorem 2.36 Baby Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466224/confusion-in-theorem-2-36-baby-rudin)
My question is different from this existing question, but I have understood where is the contradiction of this theorem.
Thank you for the help.

but I have a new question now. if all K_a do not contain any points in K_1, does this mean that the intersection of K_1 with all K_a is empty? and does this mean that the intersection of K_1 with any finite collection of K_a is also empty?

I am thinking of using picture to explain. suppose each K_a is a circle. Then if all circles of K_a have no overlaps with K_1, then any finite collection of K_a also have no overlaps with K_1's circle. Is this right?

Comment: Hi, welcome. For those who don't have baby Rudin at arm's reach, could you write down the theorem and the proof that you are confused about?

Comment: $K_1$ is included in the union of the (finite) collection of $G$'s, but $G_a=K_a^C$. Thus $K_1 \subset (K_{a_1} \cap K_{a_n})^C$ (De Morgan) and thus $K_1 \cap (K_{a_1} \cap K_{a_n})$ is empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusion in Theorem 2.36 Baby Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466224/confusion-in-theorem-2-36-baby-rudin)

Answer (score 1):

No, if $K_1$ has no point that belongs to every $K_\alpha$ doesn't by itself mean that intersection of $K_1$ with any collection of $K_\alpha$-s is empty. For example, consider $K_i = \{n \in \mathbb N | n > i\}$.

Contradiction is achieved by assuming $K_1 \cap \left(\bigcap\limits_\alpha K_\alpha\right) = \varnothing$ and deducing  from it that $K_1 \cap \left(\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in A}K_\alpha \right) = \varnothing$ for some **finite** $A$.

Note that statements "$K_1$ has no points contained in any other $K_\alpha$" and "no point of $K_1$ belongs to every $K_\alpha$" are different: the former means that for every point in $K_1$ and any other set $K_\alpha$, the point doesn't belong to the set, while the latter means that for every point in $K_1$ there exists set $K_\alpha$ s.t. the point doesn't belong to the set.

Comment: That's the key, why itself doesn't meant that the intersection of K_1 with any collection of K_a is empty?

Comment: Because why it would? And I gave an example when any finite intersection is non-empty, but intersection of everything is empty.

Comment: I just don't understand why if all K_a contain no points in K_1, then the intersection of finite K_a and K_1 is not empty. using picture to explain, the circle of all K_a have no overlap with K_1, then the circles of any finte K_a still have no overlap with K_1. Sorry, I just can't understand this part well even I saw your example.

Comment: I think the confusion come from phrase "every $K_\alpha$ something" - this is what quantifiers are for. Rudin says "no point of $K_1$ belongs to every $K_\alpha$". This doesn't mean that if we take point $x \in K_1$ then it doesn't belong to $K_2$. This just means that for every point $x \in K_1$ we can find a set $K_i$ s.t. $x \not\in K_i$. $K_2$ can very well intersect $K_1$. As my example shows, it can be that intersection of any finite number of $K_\alpha$ and $K_1$ is non-empty, and still statement from Rudin's assumption be true.

Comment: oh I see, thank you so much! I guess english is a key factor that prevents me from understanding analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The *point* is that we assume no point of $K_1$ belongs to each and every $K_\alpha$.  Well, if it doesn't belong to $K_\alpha$, it belongs to $G_\alpha=K_\alpha^c$.  But the $G_\alpha$'s are an open cover of $K_1$.  So $K_1$ is a subset of a union of finitely many of these, and thus $K_1$'s intersection with $\bigcap_{j=1}^n G_{\alpha_j}^c = \bigcap_{j=1}^n K_{\alpha_j}$ is empty!  That's the contratiction.

Comment: my question is I don't see where is the contradiction. I can understand why the intersection of K_1 with finite K_a is empty.

Comment: By hypothesis, the intersection of every finite collection is nonempty.

Comment: The intersection of $\{K_1, K_{\alpha_1}, \cdots, K_{\alpha_n} \}$ is nonempty by hypothesis.  But by assuming that no point of $K_1$ belongs to all of $K_\alpha$, we contradict this hypothesis.  This shows that the assumption is false (assuming the hypothesis).

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: but I still don't understand the question in the below answer. why K_1 has no points contained in any other K_a does not mean that the intersection of K_1 with any other K_a is empty.